# How to make dictionary element an object in python?

Tags: python, class, dictionary

How to make dictionary element an object in Python?

I made a class…

```
class Qs:
    def __init__(self,list1,id,quest="",mark=1):
        self.__list1=list1
        self.__id=id
        self.__quest=quest
        self.__mark=mark
        self.__list1.update({self.__id:{self.__quest:self.__mark}})
```

How can I store objects in a dictionary so I can call functions in this class like this?

```
dictionary[1].print()
```

Comment: I just made a class :
class Qs:
    def __init__(self,list1,id,quest="",mark=1):
        self.__list1=list1
        self.__id=id
        self.__quest=quest
        self.__mark=mark
        self.__list1.update({self.__id:{self.__quest:self.__mark}})
then I tried to make a dictionary and assign objects there

Comment: @Shathaaah it's not clear from your question where you went wrong, and the comment doesn't preserve whitespace so it's equally useless. Can you update your question with more code? Everything in Python is an object, so this *should* work. Something else is wrong somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

what you probably want is another class that *includes* a dictionary in it:

```
class QuestionCollection:
    def __init__(self):
        self.listofquestions = dict()
    def print(self,question_number):
        print(dictionary[question_number])
```

Then you could do this:

```
classobject = MyClass()
classobject.listofquestions[1] = Qs(...)
classobject.print(1)
```

or,

```
classobject = MyClass()
print(classobject.dictionary[1])
```

Then, you could extend this class to include other functions that operate on your entire dictionary.

Comment: I don't follow where/how you want to use the dictionary in this case. Is the dictionary made up of Qs objects?

Comment: yes , where you can write questions without their answers .. 
I want to use it to store data within it .

Comment: You'll need to be more explicit with your question - you have a class for Questions (I would recommend calling the class something more descriptive than Qs), then you have a dictionary of questions, and you want to add custom functions to operate on that dictionary.

Comment: yeah , something like that